# How to add a relationship or reference with AutoForm in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I use `meteor-autoform` to insert documents in a collection. My `Items` has a field `groupId`. How can I insert this group id when I'm submitting my item form.

```
<template name="itemForm">
  {{#autoForm type="insert" collection=Collections.Items}}
    {{> afQuickField name="name"}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add item</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
    </div>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

I could create another field containing my group id but I don't want the user to see this field.

How can I set the `groupId` "behind the scenes"?

Comment: on your field you can add `autoform: {omit: true}` to hide the field in the form

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need [a hook](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#onsubmit). Also you need to set an ID for the form, let's say `addItemForm`.

```
//Anywhere in your client code
Autoform.hooks({
  addItemForm : {
    onSubmit : function(doc) {
      doc.groupId = /*Get the group id*/;
      this.done(); //We've finished
      return true; //Let autoForm do his default job now
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool. How do I get the group id? Right now I'm getting the id with `this.params._id` inside `Router.route('/group/:_id', {});`

Comment: If your groupId is unique, you could pass it in a global variable. Another option would be to set it on the server... Or, to provide better control, you could use a method with your form. [See the type here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#autoform-1).

Answer (score 1):

I think one solution is not this display this option to user. You need to also add `optional:true` to the field, so it will still be valid when you submit the form.

Then using the hooks, you should be able to add any other data you want

Doc is available [hooks on autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks)

I usually modify the doc on the `before insert`

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  myFormId: {
    before: {
      insert: function(doc, template) {
        //modify the document here
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `doc=this` if the template's data context is available.

For example:

```
<template name="itemForm">
  {{#autoForm id="insert-item-form" type="insert" collection=Collections.Items doc=this}}
    {{> afQuickField name="name"}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add item</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
    </div>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

In further consequence, you could setup a hook which will be triggered before the insert operation:

```
var itemsHooks = {
    before: {
        insert: function (doc) {
            doc.groupId = this.currentDoc._id;
            return doc;
        }
    }
};

AutoForm.addHooks('insert-item-form', itemsHooks);
```